# Firebase response payload different from documentation

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using firebase auth rest API for practice, and looking in the docs, the expected response from the https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyPassword?key=[API_KEY] should be:

```
{
    "kind": "identitytoolkit#VerifyPasswordResponse",
    "localId": "ZY1rJK0eYLg...",
    "email": "[user@example.com]",
    "displayName": "",
    "idToken": "[ID_TOKEN]",
    "registered": true,
    "refreshToken": "[REFRESH_TOKEN]",
    "expiresIn": "3600"
}
```

But in my responses I'm only getting:

```
{
    "kind": "identitytoolkit#VerifyPasswordResponse",
    "localId": "",
    "email": "aa@aa.com",
    "displayName": "",
    "idToken": "token",
    "registered": true
}
```

The fields expiressIn and refresh token are missing, and I also need this fields, how I can solve this?

Comment: Are you passing `returnSecureToken` set to `true`?

Comment: Yes, I've tried it but had the same response.